# Closing a QWidget opened from a QMainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt, qwidget

I need to show a `QWidget`, which code is written in another module, when a certain button is pressed. To accomplish this, I wrote this code:

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    #A lot of stuff in here

    #The button is connected to the method called Serial_connection
    self.connect(self.btn_selection_tool3, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.Serial_connection)

  def Serial_connection(self):
    LiveData.LiveData(self).show()
```

Doing this, I open a `QWidget` and it works fine. But, when I want to close this `QWidget`, I can not do it. This is the code of the `QWidget`:

```
class LiveData(QWidget):
  def __init__(self,parent = None):
    super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
    #Another stuff in here

    #I create a "close" button connected to another method 
    self.connect(self.closeBtn, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.StopAndClose)

  def StopAndClose(self):
    print "Closing window"
    self.close()  #HERE IS WHERE I HAVE THE PROBLEM
```

I´ve tried several options like: `self.close()`, `self.accept()` or even  `sys.exit(1)`. The problem with the latter `sys.exit(1)` is that it closes the `QWidget` and the `QMainWindow`. So, how can I close this `QWidget` only? Hope you can help me.

Comment: How is this `QWidget` showing?  I'm imagining it's getting overlaid on top of your current widget.  Do you want it to open in another dialog?

Comment: The `QWidget` appears after I click the `self.btn_selection_tool3` button in the  `QMainWindow` , which calls the `Serial_connection` method, wich calls the `show()` method to show the QWidget. I need to close this last one, and I can´t do it using `self.close()`

Comment: Yeah, it's just placing the widget on top of you main window without positioning it (like it would if you had placed it inside a layout).  `close` doesn't do anything because it doesn't make sense in the context of `QWidgets`.  You can delete the widget by calling `.deleteLater()` on it.  But I still think you should make it a `QDialog` or else make a permanent widget in your main window and just show/hide or enable/disable it rather than continually creating and deleting it (especially without properly positioning it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want your `QWidget` to be a `QDialog`.  If it's a temporary modal widget, you should be calling the dialog like this

```
dialog = LiveData.LiveData(self)
dialog.exec_()
```

If you just want to show the dialog at the same time as your main window, and users are meant to interact with both (though from a design perspective, this doesn't sound like a great idea), you can continue to use `.show()`

Also, you should use the new-style signal/slot syntax.  The old syntax hasn't been used for many years.

```
self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.StopAndClose)
```

Though, for a `QDialog` you can just do

```
self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.accept)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked like this. Can I ask you how can I detect when this dialog is closed?

Comment: Generally, you listen for the accepted or rejected event.  If you're using exec_ then you just wait for the function to return

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. Thank you again